# why is python program not displaying results

Tags: python

Someone kindly assist, I have been keenly following this tutorial but I am stack here, why Am  I getting nothing after running this code? I am new to python, kindly assist.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Don't post screenshots post your code.

Comment: Because you haven't created an instance of the class and called the method. You've just created the template for the class

Comment: As said, please update your question to include the code rather than a screenshot.

The error in the code is the indentation: you want the last two lines to be at the top-most level.

Comment: You had indentation issues in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a class but haven't called it anywhere. This is because the code for creating an instance of the class is inside the class itself. You should be very careful about indentations in python. Here's the fixed code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        self.first_name = first_name


name = Person('John')
print(name.first_name)
```

Comment: Thank you friends, this was my very first post on stack overflow, I have learnt something indeed, I didn't know how to post the code that's why I uploaded a screenshot,,

Comment: No problem. Please upvote and mark as correct if my answer solved your issue.

Comment: @samuel: to post code, copy-paste it into your question (or answer), select the whole code block, and hit ctr+k (or click the "code" button - the button with braces - in the editor's menubar).

Comment: @NinadGaikwad please, edit your question, remove the screenshot and add the code.